# Not able to create a new repo in Gerrit

Tags: ssh, gerrit

I'm getting a connection to my gerrit server through SSH.

```
ssh -p 29418 fredrik@localhost
```

gives me this output

```
****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

Hi Fredrik Pettersson, you have successfully connected over SSH.

Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

git clone ssh://fredrik@fredrik-VirtualBox:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git

Connection to localhost closed.
```

So it seems to me that I have a connection to gerrit. But I can't create a repo...
When executing the command

```
ssh -p 29418 fredrik@localhost gerrit create-project --name projects/project_name
```

I'm getting the error message

```
create project not permitted
```

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "Create Project" permission on Gerrit.

See more info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#capability_createProject).